# Update preview does not work

Tags: experience-manager, web8

I'm trying to get Experience Manager to work in an environment with a typical blueprint:

- Content Parent where we create components
- Site Parent where we create  pages
- Web site publication from which we publish to the broker

I have changed the inline editing settings for the web site publication, to indicate where the components and pages are managed, like this:

[image: Inlined Editing settings]

When I do this, inline editing works and changes to the content are stored in the CM database. However, the update preview does not. I don't see my changes on the page when I press that button, and the button always has the warning icon and shows the message that the page is out of date.

What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like classic Session Preview issues. Check your caching settings if using a dynamic approach and you've ruled out everything else.

Comment: When I don't use those inline editing settings, but instead I localize the component in the website publication, everything works fine. So I don't think caching is the problem.

Comment: Just looked again - it looks like you've got the settings the wrong way round. Context for Pages = 020 Global Content? Context for Components = 050 Master Web? Doesn't sound right to me. I think you want those swapped.

Comment: It turns out that the blueprint configuration had nothing to do with it. Session preview is not working at all. I will ask a new question about that.